# how to test the type of the widgets returned by get_children()?

Tags: c++, c++14, gtkmm

using `get_children()` on a `Gtk::Container` returns a `std::vector<Gtk::Widget*>`(widgets contained by the container).

a `Gtk::Entry` inherits from `Gtk::Widget`. Of course specific `Gtk::Entry` functions like `get_text()` cannot be called by a `Gtk::Widget`.

For solving this problem, I can cast `Gtk::Widget` to `Gtk::Entry`, but you see the problem now, how can I deal if there is some other widget in the container, let say a `Gtk::Button` ?

```
  for ( auto* widgetOfTheEvilDead : ContainerCoffin->get_children() ) 
  {
    if ( widgetOfTheEvilDead->get_visible() /*shared by all widget*/ )
    {
      // do something if i'm an entry, e.g.:
      text = static_cast<Gtk::Entry*>( widgetOfTheEvilDead )->get_text();

      if ( text == "Rotting Christ")
        this->music->play("Lucifer Over Athens");
    }

  }
```

to be complete, in my case I'm not using a `Gtk::Entry` but my own widget wich inherits from a `Gtk::Entry` :

```
class Tombstone
: public Gtk::Entry
{
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `dynamic_cast` is for:

```
if (auto p = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Entry*>(widgetOfTheEvilDead)) {
    test = p->get_text();
}
```

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine What do you want to do in the case where there is a `Gtk::Button`?

Comment: in the case of a Gtk::Button, I can't call get_text, but let say I want to change is name, `set_label("something")`

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine Then use `dynamic_cast` to test if a cast at runtime would succeed (which I did above). Then you can call `set_label`.